# Replace string using php preg_replace

Tags: php

Hi all i know preg_replace can be used for formatting string but i need help in that concerned area my url will be like this

http://www.example.com/index.php/
also remove the http,https,ftp....sites also

what i want is to get 
result as

example.com/index.php

Comment: Are you fetching these url from DB?

Comment: Removing the protocol is easy. But why would you want to remove the subdomain? That changes the URL.

Comment: Is there really a need to remove subdomain? Can input be vary it always contain a subdomain or sometime url comes without subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo preg_replace("~(([a-z]*[:](//))|(www.))~", '', "ftp://www.example.com");
```

Comment: @vishnu : check the answer now. It is working all combination as above. Is there any variation in `www` also

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/index.php/';
$strpos = strpos($url,'.');
$output = substr($url,$strpos+1);
```

Comment: What exactly will the input format of the url be?  Your question has only one example format.

Comment: Also, you need to trim the / from the end (if you want the format specified by OP).

Answer (score 0):

```
$parts=parse_url($url);
unset($parts['scheme']);
//echo http_build_url($parts);   
echo implode("",$parts);
```

**EDIT**

To use `http_build_url` you needs `pecl_http` you can use implode as alternate

Comment: It should be noted that ones needs `pecl_http` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
  $url = "http://www.example.com/index.php";
  $parts = parse_url($url);
  unset($parts['scheme']);

  echo preg_replace('/^((ww)[a-z\d][\x2E])/i', '', join('', $parts));
```

Output

> example.com/index.php

Example #2

```
$url = "http://ww3.nysif.com/Workers_Compensation.aspx";
```

Output

> nysif.com/Workers_Compensation.aspx